# Ajax request to fetch partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, partial-views

I have my main view like this:

<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage" %>

Index

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="../../Scripts/MicrosoftMvcAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<h2>
    Index</h2>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#mylink').click(function() {
            $('#resultpartial1').load(this.href);
            return false;
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $('#mysecondlink').click(function() {
            $('#resultpartial1').load(this.href, { id: 123 });
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>

<%= Html.ActionLink("click me","Partial1","Foo",new MyViewModel { Foo = "123" , Bar="456" },new { id = "mylink" }) %>
<%= Html.ActionLink("click me second link","Partial2", "Foo", new { id = "123" }, new { id = "mysecondlink" }
```

) %>

and controller like this:

```
public class FooController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /Foo/

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Partial1(string id)
    {
        // TODO: use the id to fetch the model from somewhere
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel { Bar = "a", Foo = "1" };
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Partial2(string id)
    {
        // TODO: use the id to fetch the model from somewhere
        MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel { Bar = "b", Foo = "2" };
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

}

and partial views like this :

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

Foo: 

Bar:

<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl" %>

Foo: 

Bar:

I am always getting values set by controller actions. I want to set values in view and pass to partial view. How can I do this ?

Comment: any solution / hint for this?

Comment: what do you have so far? can you post some code?

Comment: I have a view where I need two links. and I have two partial views and a model class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a view model

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

and a controller:

```
public class FooController: Controller
{
    public ActionResult Partial1(string id)
    {
        // TODO: use the id to fetch the model from somewhere
        MyViewModel model = ...
        return View(model);
    }

    public ActionResult Partial2(string id)
    {
        // TODO: use the id to fetch the model from somewhere
        SomeOtherViewModel model = ...
        return View(model);
    }

}
```

a corresponding partial view:

```
<%@ Control 
    Language="C#" 
    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<AppName.Models.MyViewModel>" 
%>
<div>Foo: <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo) %></div>
<div>Bar: <%= Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Bar) %></div>
```

and finally in your main view you could have a link:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "click me", 
    "Partial1", 
    "Foo", 
    new { id = "123" }, 
    new { id = "mylink" }
) %>
<div id="resultpartial1" />
```

which could be AJAXified:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#resultpartial1').load(this.href);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Now of course if the id parameter is known only with javascript you could do this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "click me", 
    "Partial1", 
    "Foo", 
    null, 
    new { id = "mylink" }
) %>
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mylink').click(function() {
        $('#resultpartial1').load(this.href, { id: 123 });
        return false;
    });
});
```

---

UPDATE:

And for the second link:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink(
    "click me second link", 
    "Partial2", 
    "Foo", 
    new { id = "123" }, 
    new { id = "mysecondlink" }
) %>
<div id="resultpartial2" />
```

and then:

```
$(function() {
    $('#mysecondlink').click(function() {
        $('#resultpartial2').load(this.href, { id: 123 });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: @Darin: Where to put this: @model AppName.Models.MyViewModel
<div>Foo: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Foo)</div>
<div>Bar: @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Bar)</div>

Comment: @asif, I've modified my code to use the WebForms view engine as you haven't specified. You put this code in `~/Views/Foo/Partial1.ascx` if you are using WebForms view engine and in `~/Views/Foo/Partial1.cshtml` if you are using Razor.

Comment: @asif, mind sharing what error or you expect me reading your mind?

Comment: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyViewModel>' does not contain a definition for 'DisplayFor' and no extension method 'DisplayFor' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<MyViewModel>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @asif, try like this then: `<%: Model.Foo %>` but `Html.DisplayFor` should work. What version of MVC are you using? Please try this in a newly created project from scratch.

Comment: @asif, OK, that explains it. Indeed there is no DisplayFor helper in MVC 1. So the correct way to do this is: `<%= Html.Encode(Model.Foo) %>`. And next time when you ask a question make sure you provide all the relevant information about your scenario.

Comment: ok, Model.Foo worked. What I got is main view with two links. When I click one link, partial view one shows up, when I click other link, partial view opens up in new page. I want to show second partial view on click of second link

Comment: @asif, then do the same for the second link as you did for the first. Just change the id of the link: `$('#mysecondlink').click(function() { $('#resultpartial1').load(this.href, { id: 123 }); return false; });`

Comment: @asif, updated, but this seems so obvious that it shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Darin: How can I pass value to partial view and receive them in partial view using these links ?

Comment: @asif, I already showed in my answer how to pass an id. To pass multiple values you could have multiple parameters in your controller action and then `.load(this.href, { id: 123, someOtherValue: 'abc' });`

Comment: @asif, you get the values passed from the view as parameters to your action. So you could use those variables to assign the properties of the view models that will be passed to the view instead of hardcoding them.

Comment: @Darin: Can you please update the code. I am very near to solution and Thanks a lot for such a wonderful  response.

Comment: @asif, `MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel { Bar = id, Foo = "2" };`.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be the problem?

Pattern with both links should be (if you use jQuery):

```
$(function(){
    // attach link clicking functionality to call controller action via Ajax
    $("#LinkID").click(function(evt) { // reference 1 below
        evt.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: $(this).attr("href"), // if link has the correct URL
            success: function(data) {
                $("#containerID").append(data);
            },
            error: function(xhr, status, err) {
                // Handle error ie. alert()
            }
        });
    });

    // add code for the second link
});
```

If both links work the same, then you could change selector in line *reference 1* to include both links in it. But if they work with a different container, you could add container selector as a custom attribute to the link and still use just single functionality. Change the code accordingly.

You could place links on your main view using the usual

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Link text", "action", "controller", null, new { id = "LinkID" }) %>
```

so they will have correct URL that you can use as per code above. Use controller action that returns the partial view you need to display on the client.

Comment: and how the links should look like ?

Comment: In <%= Html.ActionLink("action", "controller") %> how can I give id that will be used by ajax ?