# partial view rendering

Tags: asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I have a partial view in my Foo folder. I want to show it on my Home/index view. I am using partial render and it is trying to locate it in temp folder. How to write Renderpartial to render foo\partial view ?

regards,
Asif hameed

Comment: Could you provide more information about the layout of the files in your project as well as the code snippet that is calling `RenderPartial`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax request to fetch partial view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095400/ajax-request-to-fetch-partial-view)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get it to render just specify the path in RenderPartial like this:

```
<%Html.RenderPartial("~/Areas/FooArea/Views/Foo.ascx");%>
```

Obviously replace my example path with the path to your actual Foo partial view.

Comment: Only consideration to make with this way is that the Model that Foo.ascx is going to receive in this case is the Model available to  Home/View.  If the Foo PartialView needs to be passed a different model from the Foo controller, then you would really need to do Html.RenderAction.

Comment: @RP Niemeyer - Yep you are right if you need to worry about a model, but all he seems to be asking is how to render the actual partial view given a certain path.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call an action that returns a partial view on another controller (foo) try using Html.RenderAction.  It will allow you to pass in an action and a controller.

This post has a decent description of the differences between RenderPartial/RenderAction and when to use each one: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/when-to-use-html-renderpartial-and-html-renderaction-in-asp-net-mvc-razor-views/